# Windows .bat file "start" command does not behave as expected when giving a command line that includes "&&"

Tags: batch-file

Seems like `start` has an issue:

`start /min blender -b scene.blend -P script.py && convert *.png -append out.png`

This will run both `blender` and `convert` at the same time. Is there a way to do the following?

`start /min (blender -b scene.blend -P script.py && convert *.png -append out.png)`

Not sure if helpful but addition context to my current batch file runs a few instances of blender in parallel so the only reason I've used `start` is to run multiple instances of blender at once:

```
(
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
) | pause
(
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
start blender ... && convert ...
) | pause
```

Comment: Please read my answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564). The operator `&&` and everything right of it is interpreted by `cmd.exe` as additional command to run after execution of `start` was successful. In other words once `start` finished starting `blender` successfully, the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` continues and executes now itself `convert` while `blender` is running as separate process parallel to `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. Open a command prompt, run `start /?` and read the output help.

Comment: Please note that `start` starts `blender` (whatever this is) and not `cmd.exe` which is required to interpret `&&`. You could use `start "Blend and convert" /min %ComSpec% /D /C "blender -b scene.blend -P script.py && convert *.png -append out.png"` to start another command process with a minimized console window with title `Blend and convert` which executes first `blender` and when this executable/script finished with exit code 0 runs next `convert` and finally closes itself. The command process processing the batch file immediately continues processing it. Is that really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mofi explained, the `&&` is not executed inside the new cmd window, it's executed directly after the `start` started `blender`.
But with escaping them with `^&^&` it works as expected.

```
start /min blender -b scene.blend -P script.py ^&^& convert *.png -append out.png
```

You could also use the `/B` option to stay in the same cmd window, to avoid the opening of many new windows.

Sometimes it's also a good idea to start a secondary batch file instead of building a complex single line command.

```
start /B cmd /c execute.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start /wait /b blender -b scene.blend -P script.py && start /wait /b convert *.png -append out.png
```